# lucene.net.dll doesn't work on server(?)

Tags: dll, lucene.net

my application works on my local server, but when i put it on our server the lucene classes 
throw errors.
do i have to install the DLL on the IIS server?

i'm using visual studio 08, after publishing my website i put it on the server.

does anybody know a solution?

greetings,
tyzak

Comment: hmm... i'm back @work on the 4th jan. , but there was no specific error, but i reduced the code step by step and the error was thrown at the declaration of a Lucene Class  (like Dim analyzer As Analyzer()...)

Comment: i cant read the errors, there is just a runtime error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't already, you'll need to put the DLL into the website's `bin` folder.

If you want a more specific answer, please provide more details.

Comment: i put the DLL in the bin folder,
hmm more details,.... well i tried to add the whole published folder to the server, it didn't work ;  then i tried just to add the .aspx website, that also didn't word, and at least i just put the .aspx website and the dll as such on the server what also didn't word :>

i reduced the code step by step an by declaring the class it throws an error,

it's a IIS Server, with the right asp.net version declared,
hmm...
what else should i say?

greetings, tyzak